# Поиск последнего числа в тексте

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
random_ 123 _text 456 random_text_end
```

Подскажите пожалуйста каким будет регулярное выражение для поиска `456` в данной строке если не известно: будет ли `random_ 123 _text` и будет ли `random_text_end`? Главное условие что искомое число последнее в строке при этом как до, так и после может быть что угодно.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто перебором найти последнее вхождение:

```
   //Основной метод приложения
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String text = "random_ 123 _text 456 random_text_end";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        String result = null;
        while (matcher.find()){
            result = matcher.group(0);
        }

        //Тут обрабатываем результат
        String resultHandler = result; //result = "456"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Цикл сработает, но можно решить и одним выражением: `(\d+)[^\d]*$` (группа цифр, после которой до конца строки цифры не встречаются).

На Java будет выглядеть так:

```
String text = "random_ 123 _text 456 random_text_end";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)[^\\d]*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
//если цифр в строке нет, то будет null.
String result = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
```

Comment: Я пробовал подобный вариант, но он у меня не сработал, потому и предложил решение через цикл.

Comment: @СергейИгнахин нормальное решение с циклом, просто вариант с регуляркой дает тот же результат (https://ideone.com/27SiJv) и мне кажется более прямолинейным

Comment: я с вами полностью согласен. Просто у меня не сработало)